# Calculating concentration of an ionic compound

Tags: solubility

$n$ liters of $k$ M $\ce{NaCl}$ are poured into $m$ liters of $l$ M $\ce{NaCl}$. Determine $\ce{[NaCl]}$, $\ce{[Na^+]}$, and $\ce{[Cl^{-}]}$.

Comment: Hi Okarin, please show us your efforts, what have you done so far? Have a look to the [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142) in this site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it as simple as possible :)

If both initial solutions are not saturated and all the $\ce{NaCl}$ is dissolved, this will not change upon mixing.

**If in doubt with the result of a calculation, have a look at the units!**

Concentrations are given as the quotient of moles and volume, $c = \frac{n}{V}$, the unit apparently is $\mathrm{mol \cdot l^{-1}}$. The absolute amount of $\ce{NaCl}$ in the first solution is therefore given as $n = c\cdot V$. (Note that this is not the n in your question ;).

The new $\ce{NaCl}$ concentration is the sum of the moles, divided by the new total volume:
$c = \frac{(k\cdot n)+(l\cdot m)}{m+n}$

Unless given further information, it is safe to assume that $\ce{NaCl}$ still is fully dissociated after mixing.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my opinion you do need the dissociatiion constant for NaCl

```
                         `NaCl          ->Na    +        Cl` 

initial conc.             k*n+m*l          0              0 
change at equilibrium     -a(k*n+m*l)    +a(k*n+m*l)     +a(k*n+m*l) 
final conc.               k*n+m*l(1-a)   k*n+m*l(1+a)    k*n+m*l(1+a)
```

where a is the degree of dissociation

Kb=  2*(k*n+m*l)(1+a)/k*n+m*l(1-a)=   2*(1+a)/(1-a)

where kb is the dissociation constant for nacl

so when you have the "kb" the you can find "a" and then put it in the formula under Na or Cl at final conc. to get their concentration